# Webcam to 3D scanner

Tags: webcam, scanner, 3d-graphics

Is there any software which will allow my webcam to turn into a 3d scanner?

Comment: what operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talk about timing!

I do not think anything like this exists yet, but someone posted a link on Twitter yesterday to a research project at Cambridge University - a program called Proforma.

It has not yet been released, but I think they are working on it / it will be out soon.

[Here is the link to a review.](http://scitedaily.wordpress.com/2009/11/25/building-3d-models-on-the-fly-using-a-webcam/)

[Here is a link to the official page.](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/~qp202/)

Answer (score 0):

Wil's information is indeed very fresh, as I also read about it just a few days ago.

But you'd want to look also at [**DAVID 3D Scanner**](http://www.david-laserscanner.com/), which is already available but more expensive.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be cool to own a 3d printer like CupCake CNC made by MakerBot Industries.  Their blog is a really interesting resource for DIY, fabrication, and 3d scanning.  You might like the "Argon's DIY Scanner" video: http://blog.makerbot.com/2009/04/12/diy-scanner-action/.  I think it would be fairly straight forward to adapt to a webcam.